# Poll module for blogs

Tags: 7, polls

I have a blog that needs a poll attached to it.  I've looked at a few modules, but they seem to be buggy.

Any suggestions on a good poll module or methodology?

Comment: Can you be specific and let us know which modules you have tried?  What was wrong with each of them?  Are you willing to write your own module, if need be?

Comment: I haven't tried any yet -- just read comments on them, and haven't found one I can just "attach" to individual blogs.  I would write one, but I'm under a time crunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the Advanced Poll module, and it seems to handle what I need.  It lets you display the poll as a block, but doesn't have an option to get rid of the author info.  It looks like the best one so far.